# What's the purpose of trimming loops at ends of every coil?

Tags: rolling

Recently I visited the steel industry, I discover contract workers trimming loops of head and tail side of every coil:

[image]

> **For 12mm** rebar coils, they have to trim **8** loops at head and **3** loops at tail side.

What's the purpose of trimming loops at ends of every coil?

Comment: I would look for a political or religious reason, or inadequate training.  Rebar has very wide tolerance of properties so it is difficult to imagine a metallurgical reason. Until about the 70's , the bulk of rebar ( in US) was made by repurposing railroad rails , so little control of physical properties other than high carbon made it fairly hard.

Answer (score 1):

Trimming can be related to the manufacturing process.

If the process causes material at start and end to be of different quality, then removing them in order to only use the consistent product makes sense.

For example, imagine a continuous extrusion process.  Once you get the process running, the friction in the die subjects your material to certain necessary pressures.  Unless there is leading material already in the die to back-pressure your current material, that pressure treatment is not achieved.